# Admob No ads to show

Tags: react-native, admob

I’m using react-native-admob package for show ads. This package working properly in android. But iOS version mostly my ads doesn’t showing. Someone can help me ?

Comment: capture logs and upload in your question

Comment: @AmodGokhale i'm using testfligt for ios. My Ads always return "Request Error: No ad to show".
I'm understand sometimes doesn't find ads. But this is to much. Ads Request is 200 match request 1

Comment: that is valid error... based on country, type of app  etc fill rate is low for admob now a days

Comment: @AmodGokhale how can i to raise this match request ?

Comment: Any solution for this?